# Looping foreach, grabbing data from db and insert into JS

Tags: javascript, php

I have some JS that display a countdown timer, but this is only showing for one item on the page and i need it to be used in the PHP foreach loop I have. this code below is within the foreach loop.

```
                 <div class="countdown-timer">
                    <strong>Time Left - </strong> <span id="countdown"></span>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                    // set the date we're counting down to
                    var target_date = new Date("<?php echo $listing->ends; ?>").getTime(); // echo would return 2014-07-15

                    // variables for time units
                    var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

                    // get tag element
                    var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

                    // update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
                    setInterval(function () {

                        // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
                        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
                        var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

                        // do some time calculations
                        days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
                        seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

                        hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
                        seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

                        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
                        seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

                        // format countdown string + set tag value
                        countdown.innerHTML = days + " days " + hours + " hrs "
                        + minutes + " min " + seconds + " secs ";

                    }, 1000);

                </script>
```

Comment: so you want to have a countdown timer for each item that your foreach php code produces?

Comment: yes exactly that, has each item will have a different timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a unique ID for each element, that way you can reference each element individually.

In addition, you'd be wise to take the javascript block out of the php `foreach` loop. Instead, create an array of each element's ID, then use that array to `setInterval` on each item via javascript. That way, you don't repeat a bunch of JS code.

Rough example:

```
<!-- php code here to loop and create these html elements -->
<div class="countdown-timer">
        <strong> Time Left - </strong> <span id="countdown-INSERT_ID_FROM_PHP_HERE"></span>
</div>
<!--end php code to create html -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var createCountdown = function(id, date) {
        var target_date = new Date(date).getTime();
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
        var countdown = document.getElementById(id);

        setInterval(function() {
            var current_date = new Date().getTIme();
            var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

            days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

            hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

            minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
            seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

            // format countdown string + set tag value
            countdown.innerHTML = days + " days " + hours + " hrs "
        + minutes + " min " + seconds + " secs ";
        }, 1000);
    };

    // USE PHP TO MAKE THIS ARRAY
    // POPULATE IT WITH OBJECTS THAT LOOK LIKE THIS
    // { id: "countdown-6", date: "2014-07-01" }
    var allCounters = [
        { id: "countdown-6", date: "2014-07-01" }
    ];

    allCounters.forEach(function(counter) {
        createCountdown(counter.id, counter.date);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: create a unique id not sure how i know a little js i got this script of the net.

Comment: the html elements are what need unique IDs. to do that, you could just increment by 1 for each of the items you have. something like "countdown_1" "countdown_2" "countdown_3" etc. Have your php loop generate that, and either have it generate an array of your IDs or if you use that simple naming convention with countdown_INDEX then you can just use the length of your data array to iterate as many times as needed and create timers for them.

Comment: mmm, still not sure I follow you on how to do this.

Comment: added php to add the id on like so - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8684ddb000dea4191f1c but still only one timer is showing.

Comment: but that all counters ar i'm then going to have to manually add these.

Comment: what? not sure what exactly that sentence meant but this way is how you can dynamically generate them with php and javascript. you wouldn't have to do anything manually. you use a loop in php to generate the html elements. you use the same data to populate the array in javascript below and then the javascript will automatically create a countdown for you.

Comment: this bit var allCounters = [
        { id: "countdown-6", date: "2014-07-01" }
    ]; i'd have to manual add these in.

Comment: no, you wouldn't. just make a loop like you did previously for the elements.

Comment: Ha! sorted it sorry had a brain freeze then but came to me just after I posted.

Comment: that's great, congrats. come again if you need more help.